# how to run all the tests over a list of browsers?

Tags: python, automated-tests, python-behave

I am writing a test suite with python-behave and want to run my tests over a list of `platforms-browsers-browserversions`.

What I have tried so far is to pass the variables from feature to step definition which would work perfectly for one scenario. 
Here's how I did it.

```py
Feature: Test Main Page 

  Scenario Outline: Test Button with <browser>
    Given I go to main page with "<platform>""<Browser>""<BrowserVersion>"
    Then I can see Fahrzeug finden Button

    Examples: Browsers
        | platform        | Browser | BrowserVersion  |
        | Windows 10      | Chrome  | 76.0            |
```

What I want to do is to build a list of `platforms-browsers-..` and use it with all or a subset of the tests. 
so the list should be accessible to all tests somehow. 
One possible solution is to write a macro feature that run all the steps which means that I will have to run all the tests each time!

Comment: Do you want the list of `platforms-browsers-..` to be able to be controlled at the `feature` file level or at the `steps` code level?

Comment: I guess it should be better on `features` level. but if i can use it on `steps` level and still can use it with different scenarios why not!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you basically want to have a parametrised test suite that runs a number of tests (features / scenario) based on a browser, browser.version, etc. And you want to run it for each parameter combination from above.

POTENTIAL SOLUTIONS:

- External automation that iterates over browsers, etc. and runs `behave -D browser=$CURRENT_BROWSER -D browser_version=$CURRENT_BROWSER_VERSION ...` for each iteration by using userdata parameters as context to the test run.
- Internal automation: Use behave feature file as automation script similar to the approach above but it needs a step like `When I run "behave -D browser=<Browser> -D browser_version=<BrowserVersion> ...more_here` by using the ScenarioOutline from above (meaning a similar one)

HINTS:

- External automation uses a "build script" (shell script, makefile, invoke task, ...) to run behave N times, once for each parameter combination
- Internal automation is a two stages approach. You use a feature file in STAGE_1 to run behave with a number of other feature files in STAGE_2. STAGE_2 is basically the execution of one row in your examples table of the ScenarioOutline above. STAGE_1 is basically the trampoline to run STAGE_2.

SEE ALSO:

- [Behave userdata description](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5/?highlight=userdata#index-7)
- [Example: Use feature file to run behave as automation script](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/more.features/formatter.json.validate_output.feature)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from our comments, there are 2 ways that I can see of accomplishing your goal:

## Use Tags

You can take advantage of tags and access them from your `scenario` [objects](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#behave.model.Scenario). What you should note is the following:

[image: documentation snippet]

This is very important for what we're about to do. There is a tutorial on how to control things with tags, which can be found [here](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#controlling-things-with-tags), but the general idea would be to have your scenario file structured like so:

```
@Windows10_Chrome_76.0
@Windows10_Firefox_68.0
Scenario Outline: Test Button with the browser
    Given I go to main page with the browser
    Then I can see Fahrzeug finden Button
```

In `environment.py`, you would have:

```
def before_scenario(context, scenario):      
    for tag in scenario.tags:
        (platform, browser, browserVersion) = tag.split('_')

        if browser == "Chrome":
            # Initialize the browser with platform, browser, etc.
            context.browser = WebDriver.Chrome()
        elif browser == "Firefox":
            # Initialize the browser with platform, browser, etc.
            context.browser = WebDriver.Firefox()
```

In your `steps` file, you would then have access to the browser:

```
@given(u'I go to main page with the browser')
def step_impl(context)
    context.browser.get('https://yourUrl.com')
```

Depending on how you see it, the drawback, or perhaps the benefit, is that every scenario will need to be tagged with your `platform-browser-browserVersion`, which is a bit cumbersome. But the main benefit is that you have much more control over which browser is tested on.

## Use a class

You *could* have some sort of a browser-handling class, like a `BrowserHandler` singleton. However, going with this approach neglects the benefits of Python Behave, so I advise it.

Comment: This do not work, because different browsers are set looping as described... but they do before scenario execution. This means once the scenario starts the browser is set to the last value given by the loop. And the scenario will only execute once. I also tried using before_tag instead of before_scenario, but the result is the same. Toying around with fixtures ability yield instead of return doesn't help either, as cleanups are executed in row after the scenario/feature is finished. So basically this approach is not valid to automate recursive executions fo features/scenarios.